# rails 3 form_for undefined variable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got a undefined variable or method error when I try to render a partial view which is a form. The code like following:

in a partial view file, show.html.erb:

```
<ul class="users">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= render 'pending' %>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

in _pending.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for current_user.friendships.build(:friendb_id => user.id) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :friendb_id %></div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Confirm" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The rspec error is:
undefined local variable or method `user'

I tried:

```
<%= render :partial => 'pending', :locals => {:user => user} %>
```

but it still doesn't work

Anyone knows why the form cannot find user variable?

Comment: Is `:friendb_id` correct, or should it be `:friend_id`?

Comment: Also, try `<%= render :partial => 'pending', :user => user %>`